# Poker five in Java in boolean[][] array

Tags: java, methods, poker

I have problem with recognizing flushes and straights. I operate in `2D boolean array` and it must be a `boolean array` nothing else. Could somebody help me in writing this method?

I already have logically incorrect methods, but I don't know how to solve it:

```
public static Boolean isFlush(boolean[][] hand) { // 5 cards same color
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            if (hand[i][j] == true && hand[i][j+1] == true && hand[i][j+2] == true && hand[i][j+3] == true && hand[i][j+4] == true) {
                found = true;
            }
        }}
    System.out.println("Found from flush: " + found);
    return found;
}

public static Boolean isStraight(boolean[][] hand) { // straight patter example 4,5,6,7,8
    boolean found = false;
    int pom = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (hand[i][j] == true || hand[i][j+1] == true || hand[i][j+2] == true || hand[i][j+3] == true || hand[i][j+4])
            pom++;
           // System.out.println("straight value: "+i);
        }
    }
            return pom==5;

        }
```

Working Straight method but step by step writed

```
public static Boolean isStraight(boolean[][] hand) { // straight patter example 4,5,6,7,8
    boolean found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if ((hand[0][j] == true || hand[1][j] == true || hand[2][j] == true || hand[3][j] == true)
                    && (hand[0][j+1] == true || hand[1][j+1] == true || hand[2][j+1] == true || hand[3][j+1] == true)
                    && (hand[0][j+2] == true || hand[1][j+2] == true || hand[2][j+2] == true || hand[3][j+2] == true)
                    && (hand[0][j+3] == true || hand[1][j+3] == true || hand[2][j+3] == true || hand[3][j+3] == true)
                    && (hand[0][j+4] == true  || hand[1][j+4] == true  || hand[2][j+4] == true  || hand[3][j+4] == true ))
                found = true;
        }
    return found;

}
```

Comment: What are the exact errors that you encounter when you run the code? I am guessing that you are encountering an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error in your if statements but I just want to be sure with it.

Comment: I don't have errors, it's logical problem because we can have cards like :
allcards[1][1]  / [1][3] / [1][5] / [1][6] / [1][9] = true; and both methods return false

Comment: Also, what does it mean if `hand[i][j] == true`? What makes the value of a particular element of the array `true` or `false`?

Comment: hand[i][j] == true <- there is problem we can have hand[i][j] and next card in flush can be hand[i][j+3] and my if return false, simple example allcards[1][1] / [1][3] / [1][5] / [1][6] / [1][9] = true;

Comment: I'm guessing that ``hand[i][j] == true`` means the card is in the player hand.

Comment: right, and i - color j - value, we have 4 colors and 13 values

Comment: Straight: Brute force way is to step from j=0 to 8 and always check consecutive 5 = 9*5 = 45 if statements. There is a dynamic programming solution which only steps j=0 to 12 and no extra check of 5 consecutive.  This is a small problem so no need for DP?  I can post if interested.

Comment: Solved by Abdul Ahad, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like the following

```
public static Boolean isFlush(boolean[][] hand) { // 5 cards same color
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int count = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            if(hand[i][j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if(count == 5) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static Boolean isStraight(boolean[][] hand) { // straight patter 
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        int count = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                if (hand[k][i + j]) {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(count == 5) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Abdul Ahad in straight we can have hand[i][j] next can be hand[i+2][j+1] next one hand[i][j+2] etc,  so it's wrong solve

Comment: yeah, I'll edit it

Comment: @Jedyn - ok, updated it

Comment: I don't know how Aces are handled in boolean arrray ``hand``, but do you remember that you can have a straight like A/2/3/4/5 or T/J/Q/K/A?

Comment: yeah @Jedyn you'll have to write specific logic for the aces as pointed out by Guillaume

Comment: I have it, player enters data to String, then i split it to array and chechk if(hand[i].toLowerCase.charAt(1) == 't'? if its true i replace t and add 10 to my array same solve with colors. Still i  have problem with flush. When i testing it with allcards[1][3] / [1][4] / [1][5] / [1][3] / [1][7] = true; it given me false :/

Comment: @Jedyn are you using multiple decks? I see [1][3] listed twice

Comment: My mistake, I forgot about input check

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, here is the most efficient way to solve a straight, using DP

```
public static boolean isStraight(boolean[][] hand) {
    int[] straightCounter = new int[13];
    for (int j=0; j<13; j++) {
        boolean isCard =  hand[0][j] || hand[1][j] || hand[2][j] || hand[3][j];
        if (isCard) {
            if (j==0)
                straightCounter[j]=1;
            else
                straightCounter[j]=straightCounter[j-1]+1;
            if (straightCounter[j] == 5)
                return true;
            if (j==12 && straightCounter[j] == 4 && straightCounter[0] == 1)
                return true;  // the 10/J/Q/K/A scenario
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```